# Could not Insert into Database asp.net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

Something went wrong with my code. The insert code does not work. Can someone tell me what i did wrong? The code is supposed to insert the username, password and role to my database when the users click a button, however nothing appears in my database.

```
namespace Login_role
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    { 

        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["victs"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand com;

        protected void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.CommandText = "Insert into Login values(@UserName,@Password,@Role)";
            com.Parameters.Clear();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txt_UserName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_Password.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", rbtRole.SelectedValue);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lblmsg.Text = "Successfully Registered!!!";
            clear();
        }
        private void clear()
        {
            txt_UserName.Text = "";
            rbtRole.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error, exception ???

Comment: What's your connection string, and why do you think “nothing appears in my database”?

Comment: Can we assume that the code runs without error? And do you have access to your database transaction logs?

Comment: Are you sure that the database where you look for the new record is the same database against which you code works?

Comment: maybe it's just a typo, but sometimes you use "com" and sometimes you use "con" ??

Comment: You have a btn_register that has its click event hooked up?

Comment: @BWS That is possible but in this case: no.

Comment: Have you put a break point in your code to ensure that this block is executing?

Comment: Put in a try catch block and get the integer returned by ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless these are the only 3 columns in your LOGIN table, SQL Server (my assumption) will not execute your command text:

```
com.CommandText = "Insert into Login values(@UserName,@Password,@Role)";
```

This should throw an exception, however (even if there are defaults on the remaining columns):

```
"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."
```

Try listing the column names in your command text as such:

```
string sqlCmd = "Insert into Login (UserName, Password, Role) " +
                "values(@UserName,@Password,@Role)";
com.CommandText = sqlCmd;
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // <-- SQL doesn't have to guess!
```

See if this makes a difference.